# Using @Concat To Build Dynamic Expression In ADF Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to build dynamic expression using @concat activity in ADF.

I am struggling to build this expression , pls help.

My expected output expression/result  is : I want single quote around those static Values and Variables.

How do i achieve this?

```
Call DB_variables('v_environment').SCHEMA.PROC_TO_LOAD('VALUE1', 'variables('v_runtime')','VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'variables('v_environment')');
```

I tried to achieve this using expression @concat but its failing with lots of syntax error.

```
@concat('Call DB','''variables('v_environment')''','SCHEMA..PROC_TO_LOAD(''VALUE1'', '''variables('v_runtime')''','''VALUE2''', '''VALUE3''', '''variables('v_environment')''')
```

but unfortunaley this is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the expected output expression, you want single quotes around those static Values and Variables. Below is the correct expression.

```
@concat('Call DB','''',variables('v_environment'),'''','.SCHEMA.PROC_TO_LOAD(''VALUE1'', ''',variables('v_runtime'),''', ''VALUE2'', ''VALUE3'', ''',variables('v_environment'),''');')
```

This expression will give the the expected output expression/result with single quotes around the static values and variables.

You can also use string interpolation in ADF to achieve the same result.

```
Call DB '@{variables('v_environment')}'.SCHEMA.PROC_TO_LOAD('VALUE1 ','@{variables('v_runtime')}','VALUE2', 'VALUE3', '@{variables('v_environment')}')
```

[image]